# Python list of global variables not updated

Tags: python, arraylist, global-variables

I have few global variables and I have a list. Within a function I am using the list and updating the values as below , but the global variables doesn't seem to be updated.

```
a = "hello"
b ="how"
c = "are you"
data = ([a,"abc","xyz"],[b,"pqr","mno"],[c,"test","quest"])
def checklist():
    global data , a, b, c
    for values in data:
        values[0] = values[1]
checklist()
print a + ":" + b + ":"+  c
```

Now when i expect the global variables to be updated which is not happening, I still see old variables, could some one explain how to update global variables from the list.

Comment: `print data` before calling your function. You'll find there is no such thing as `a`, `b` or `c`. They are variables references objects. The list holds its own reference to those same objects.

Comment: First of all, this code won't work  - the very first line is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: true, the data shows global values before the function call, i would like to update few global variables using a generic function, is there a way to update actual variables using variable reference objects

Comment: I think you are binding to the `data` new values, you are not updating `a`, `b` or `c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop in data changes data's value, which won't change other variable.

When you run `values[0] = values[1]`, it means values[0] repoints to another object, but `a` will stays the same.

```
In [52]: a = '12'

In [53]: li = [a, 'b', 'c']

In [54]: id(li[0])
Out[54]: 140264171560632

In [55]: id(a)
Out[55]: 140264171560632

In [56]: li[0] = 'a'

In [57]: li
Out[57]: ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [58]: a
Out[58]: '12'

In [60]: id(li[0])
Out[60]: 140264267728616

In [61]: id(a)
Out[61]: 140264171560632
```

Comment: okay got it, Thanks for the info, is there a way out to achieve this , i mean to update a bunch of global variables using a generic function ?

Comment: I dont' think you can do that, I think list bahave like a function, that means it has a another scope, you can't change outter variable in a function, right?

Answer (score 0):

You intend the values in data to be changes in the for loop?

The reason that's not  happening is that you're changing `value`, not the actual data.

Comment: nope the list gets updated, when i print data after the function call, it shows updated info, but the variables still remain as they were declared globally

Comment: What variables remain unchanged? `a,b,c`?

Comment: yes variables a,b, c remain as  "hello", "how", "are you"

Comment: Why do you expect them to change? You're not changing them anywhere. In the for loop, you're reassigning data, but you're never reassigning `a,b,c`

Answer (score 0):

```
a,b,c = "hello", "how", "are you"
data = ([a,"abc","xyz"],[b,"pqr","mno"],[c,"test","quest"])
def checklist():
    global data , a, b, c
    for values in data:
        values[0] = values[1]
checklist()
```

---

```
print a + ":" + b + ":"+  c
```

hello:how:are you

```
print(data)
```

(['abc', 'abc', 'xyz'], ['pqr', 'pqr', 'mno'], ['test', 'test', 'quest'])

---

You are wrong if you want do something like this, edit a variable that you inserted in a list.

values[0] = values[1]

Set in the position 0 of values -> values[1]. But no modify a-b-c!!